# Preventing atoms from changing kind

Tags: math-mode, spacing, tex-core

In the example below, the presence of `\mycommand` changes the first minus sign into a binary operation atom, so that the spacing between `-` and `1` is increased.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\mycommand{\mbox{ abc } }
\begin{document}
\[
\mycommand -1 = -1
\]
\end{document}
```

I know that this can be dealt with on a case by case basis, but I would like to change the macro definition so that the first atom after a `\mycommand` behaves as if it were the first atom in the equation. Is this possible?

Comment: It's not `\mycommand` *per se*, but the fact that it produces `\mbox{abc}` which *is* an ordinary atom. If you want that a minus sign is not mistaken in that situation, write `\mycommand {-1}=-1`.

Comment: @egreg --- see edited question.

Comment: Sorry, but the answer is no. If `\mycommand` contributes an atom to the math list, *that* will be the first. Wouldn't it be better to show the *real* thing you want to do?

Comment: @egreg --- this more or less is what I want to do. Sometimes I have small pieces of text such as 'and' or 'as' in displayed equations, and these can affect spacing around subsequent atoms. I would like to define a macro that prevents this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rule about `\mathbin` atoms being converted to `\mathord` is different from what you're thinking it is:

> If a `\mathbin` atom is between two atoms incompatible with it being an binary operation symbol (or if it is the first atom in a math list), then consider it as `\mathord`.

Thus in `$-1=-1$`, both `-` symbols will be converted to ordinary atoms. The first one because it's the first, the second one because it's between a relation and an ordinary.

You may try

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{\mathopen{\mbox{ #1 }}}
```

so the `\mathopen` nature of the atom will disallow a `\mathbin` immediately following. TeX never inserts spaces following a `\mathopen` atom.

Assuming that what comes before this text is an ordinary atom or a `\mathclose`, nothing bad should happen as regards to spacing.

However I'd simply use

```
\[
1 = 1 \text{ and } {-1}=-1
\]
```

Comment: \begin{pedantry} I didn't say anything about the rule! I only said that I want the atom following a `\mycommand` to behave as if it were the first. \end{pedantry}

Comment: @IanThompson I had to review the rule in order to find a way out. :)